# How to call function pointer in STL

Tags: c++, stl, function-pointers

I am curious about how to call function pointer in a map structure. Here is the details:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<vector>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;
class FuncP;

typedef int(FuncP::*func) (int, int);
class FuncP
{
public:
    map<int, func> fmap;
    map<int, string> fstring;
public:
    FuncP(){}
    void initial();
    int max(int x, int y);
    int min(int x, int y);
    int call(int op, int x, int y)
    {
        return (this->*fmap[op])(x, y);
    }
};


void FuncP::initial()
{
    fmap[0] = &FuncP::max;
    fmap[1] = &FuncP::min;
    fstring[0] = "fdsfaf";
}
int FuncP::min(int x, int y)
{
    return (x<y)?x:y;
}
int FuncP::max(int x, int y)
{
    return (x<y)?y:x;   
}

int main()
{
    func h = &FuncP::max;
    FuncP *handle = new FuncP();
    handle->initial();

    cout<< handle->call(0, 1, 4);  //1
    cout<< (handle->FuncP::*fmap)[0](1,5);  //2
    return 0;
}
```

For the number 2 (handle->FuncP::*fmap)0; The compiler gives a error:

```
‘fmap’ was not declared in this scope
```

I am not sure why it happened. What the difference of the number 1 and 2 call methods?

Comment: You haven't included the header for `std::string`.

Comment: try this: `(handle->*handle->fmap[0])(1,5);` or `(*handle.*handle->fmap[0])(1,5);`

Comment: I got this. But I still do not understand the deep main idea for that. fmap is already the public variable in the class. Why I can not directly deference the fmap (i.e., (handle->*fmap[0])[1,5] )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by Piotr, a correct way would be

```
(handle->*(handle->fmap[0]))(1, 5);
```

Explanation:
`handle->fmap[0]` gives you the function pointer. To call it, you need to dereference it, giving `*(handle->fmap[0])` (parentheses optional)
 and call it on the respecting object (`handle`), leaving us with the expression above.

This is essentially the same as your above statement `(this->*fmap[op])(x, y)` except of `handle->fmap[0]`instead of`fmap[op]`.

Comment: I got this. But I still do not understand the deep main idea for that. fmap is already the public variable in the class. Why I can not directly deference the fmap (i.e., (handle->*fmap[0])[1,5] )?

Comment: Because the function referenced by fmap could as well be called on any other object of this class: `some_other_handle->*(handle->fmap[0]))(1, 5)` would result in `some_other_handle->max(1, 5)`.